# specify download path for files

Tags: nightwatch.js

As part of my test, I want to download a file to a specific path, relative to the root folder of my nightwatch project.

The download button doesn't provide any confirmation window, so the file will be downloaded immediatly after the button was clicked into some default download folder - but I don't know where and how to configure this default directory.

I use Chrome browser.

Comment: Which browser? The answer is different based on the browser you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the default download directory by using the `prefs` option. A couple things to note:

- You must specify an absolute path to the directory
- The directory must already exist on disk (or you will still get prompted to download)

---

```
'desiredCapabilities': {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'prefs': {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'default_directory': '/absolute/path/to/directory'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

It is possible to use a relative path in your config and still specify an absolute path by using `process.cwd()`. The following is an example of how to get this to work. This will only work if your config is in the root directory. For other scenarios, use `path.join()` and `__dirname` instead.

```
'default_directory': process.cwd() + '/relative/path/'
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! Just a little hint: (you forgot some `''` in your json.)

Comment: Maybe I should ask a new question but, since I run in `headless` mode, the file will not be downloaded `"chromeOptions": { "args": [ "--headless" ],"prefs": {}}`

Comment: You can also use `default_directory: require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/relative/path/')` and if directory does not exist, it will be created